# Passing Audio/ Video File to API

Tags: rest, audio, go, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the Soundcloud API (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) to upload an audio file to Soundcloud. The parameter I must pass the file in requires "binary data of the audio file" and I'm unsure how to load such a thing in Go.

My current code is as follows, but the audio file of course does not send properly.

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
w := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

label, err := w.CreateFormField("oauth_token")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
label.Write([]byte(c.Token.AccessToken))

fw, err := w.CreateFormFile("upload", "platform/young.mp3")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
fd, err := os.Open("platform/young.mp3")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer fd.Close()
_, err = io.Copy(fw, fd)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
w.Close()
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json", buf)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())
req.SetBasicAuth("email@email.com", "password")

fmt.Println(req.Form)

res, err := c.Client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the code below, as I don't have a valid Oauth token, but it may put you on the right track.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    uri := "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json"
    params := map[string]string{
        "oauth_token":    "************",
        "track[title]":   "Test Track",
        "track[sharing]": "public",
    }
    trackData := "track[asset_data]"
    path := "test_track.mp3"

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(trackData, filepath.Base(path))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(part, file)

    for key, val := range params {
        err := writer.WriteField(key, val)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        body := &bytes.Buffer{}
        _, err := body.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(resp.Header)
        fmt.Println(body)
    }
}
```